# Specifying draft order currency Shopify

Tags: node.js, api, shopify, currency

```
var draft = {
    line_items: [],
    applied_discount: '',
    currency_code: "CAD",
    currency: "CAD",
    email: "fake@email.com",
    shipping_address: {
        first_name: "John"
        last_name: "Smith"
    },
    billing_address: {
        first_name: "John"
        last_name: "Smith"
    },
}

    var item = {
        variant_id: request.query.variant[i],
        product_id: request.query.product[i],
        quantity: quantity,
        custom: true,
    }

    draft.line_items[0] = item
```

shopify-api-node: `"^2.15.0"` to create a draft order but the currency for some reason isn't getting set.

I'm setting the `currency_code` and currency to `CAD` for Canada but the draft orders always appears in `AUD` (my store is located in Australia).

I've tried many different variations of setting the draft order. Like setting:

```
currency_code, currency, currency_initials, cart_params: { currency_iso_name: "CAD" }, exchange_rate
```

But nothing works

Answer (score 1):

According to [Shopify documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/payments/shopify-payments/selling-and-getting-paid-in-different-currencies), it is not possible to allow customers to checkout in different currencies. You can use different apps or a [Shopify tutorial](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/currencies/switch-between-multiple-currencies) to display prices in different currencies but on the checkout page, default currency of your store will be used for payment.

As you already mentioned that it reverts to **AUD** and I assume that is the default currency of your Shopify store. What you are trying to achieve is not possible as of yet.

However [Shopify Unite 2018](https://www.shopify.com/enterprise/unite-2018#Multi-currency-for-Shopify-Payments) announced that Shopify will support multiple currencies for checkout for Shopify Plus customers.